# jQueryUI tabs : clear div of other tabs when tab is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page with several tabs that show similar content, to make sure I access the correct fields in the correct tab, I want to clear the contents of the divs of the other tabs as soon as the user clicks a tab.

This is the code I use :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WebShop</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/igepa.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                });
            },
            load: function(event, ui){
               $('.ui-tabs-hide').empty();  
            }                          
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/itemStructPaper/Enveloppen">Enveloppen</a></li>
        <li><a href="/itemStructPaper/GrafischKarton">Grafisch karton</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have added an example here : http://www.igepa.be/phdj/tabs/index.htm

page1.htm and page2.htm both have a form with a the same field on them but a different value, but when you select the tab for the second page you get the value of the field of the first page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using the `ui` parameter and referring to its siblings, like this:

```
   beforeLoad: function(event, ui){
      $(ui.panel).siblings('.ui-tabs-panel').empty();
    }
```

**Update:** I've just updated my code above to just change `load` for `beforeLoad` event so the siblings tab contents are removed before the page of the current tab is executed.

Comment: thanks for the quick respone Nelson, but this did not work either, what I am after is a way to clear the html content of the div fields of the other tabs, if someone clicks on tab2, the div tabs-1 and tabs-3 are cleared if I have three tabs in this example.

Comment: I think my answer is correct, but maybe is not what your are looking for, but you have to clarify on that.. Btw, your test page  http://www.igepa.be/phdj/tabs/index.htm alerts the same text because you have the text inputs from both `page1.htm` and `page2.htm` with same id `id="field1"` and the ID's must be unique so you know exactly the element you are working with.

Comment: That is exactly my point Nelson, I want to use the tabs to show the same pages ( with the same fields on them ) but with different parameters, so I want the page to "forget" everything about tab1 when the user chooses tab2

Comment: Use a `beforeload` event for that instead of `load`, see my updated answer.

Comment: That worked, thanks Nelson, can't vote up, because I lack reputation.

Comment: Thanks for that last tip, searched like crazy, found at the same time you posted this :-) Doing that, I went up to 13 rep, so not far to go now :-) Thanks again.